# Keeping DIV open after hover if mouse is inside opened DIV

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

I currently have a bit of jQuery that opens up a div below it from my menu. It works great, however It's not a drop-down but an extra menu.

I want to keep the div 'quickCourse' open if the mouse is inside that div.

So I only want the div to close if the mouse is not over the li:nth-of-type(6) or the quickCourse div. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have a feeling it's to do with mouseOver but a little unsure? - A JSfiddle of what I have so far is available here:

http://jsfiddle.net/owenoneill/REyRg/11/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".header ul.menu > li:nth-of-type(6) ").hover(
                function () {
                    $("div.quickCourse").fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    $("div.quickCourse").fadeOut();
                }
            );
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Much shorter is:             `$(document).ready(function () {
                $(".header ul.menu > li:nth-of-type(6)").hover(function() {
                    $("div.quickCourse").fadeToggle();
                });
            });`

Comment: yup it can be done using mouseover event, but I would suggest you to use CSS for this task, it would be much simpler in CSS (don't forget CSS is always efficient than jQuery for such tasks)

Comment: Well, I got a little bit stuck by doing it by CSS as the menu is very complex on the live site, see: universitycompare.com for a live version.

Comment: Any help on getting the div to stay? I am a little new to jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header ul.menu > li:nth-of-type(6)").mouseover(function() {
    $("div.quickCourse").fadeIn();
  });

  $(".header ul.menu > li:nth-of-type(6), div.quickCourse").mouseleave(function() {
    $("div.quickCourse").fadeOut();
  });
  $("div.quickCourse").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).stop(true, true).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.header ul.menu {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

.quickCourse {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #000;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>TEST 1</li>
    <li>TEST 2</li>
    <li>TEST 3</li>
    <li>TEST 4</li>
    <li>TEST 5</li>
    <li>TEST 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="quickCourse">HULLO!</div>
```

Comment: @user1077369 Ow, my bad. Edited!

Comment: That's brilliant Bram! Appreciate the help! Can I ask what the (true, true).show does as I want to understand it rather than copy and paste your code in replacement!

Comment: @user1077369 I am glad you asked. Most people just copy and paste!

jQuery is one of the best documented libraries so I suggest you read through it: http://api.jquery.com/stop/ . Basically, `true, true` gives values to the boolean `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd` respectively (default: `false`). clearQueue "clears the queue of animations" and jumpToEnd decides whether or not "the element is immediately given its target values for each CSS property".

So, when quickCourse is fading out after leaving the menu and you mouseover the element when it's fading out, all animations will be skipped.